# Can Mailchimp handle repeat automations?

Tags: email, mailchimp

I'm trying to create a Mailchimp automation for a gated asset/lead magnet. The problem is repeat visitors. I have a simple automation set up for users who are already subscribed, and ask for the asset again, which has a Profile Update trigger based on Groups.

It looks like Mailchimp can only send this automation once. Mailchimp support has confirmed that there is no way to make automations trigger repeatedly, although a reminder email can be sent to anyone who hasn't actioned an email received. I'm not 100% sure I believe them.

Am I missing something here? Is there a workaround?